# Lync 2013 Web API (UCWA) Location

Tags: lync, lync-2013

Is it possible to retrieve the location of a contact using the Lync 2013 Web API (or UCWA)?
If that is possible, could this be extended to people who are not necessarily in your contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the location property of a contact this is highly possibly in UCWA as long as you can get that contact's href ([Resources-contact](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-contact)).  Assuming you can it is simply making an additional (GET) request to their contactLocation (contactObj._links.contactLocation.href), and it should be noted that the location returned will be the location of that contact on their most active device (Lync client, browser, mobile).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it turned out that Location will not be supported by our Lync server. But thanks nevertheless !